# Rendering Movie Clip textures in Cycles

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have created on object that uses a Movie Clip as a texture. Specifically an MP4 file. I got it to render properly as an image so no issue there. My question is regarding rendering it as an animation. When i press the "Render Animation" button it seems to render the individual MP4 files (there's 5 of them) before the actual animation. Is this something that is supposed to happen? I'm asking since I haven't been able to find the process of rendering it as an animation and don't want to waste hours for nothing.

P.S. Would converting the MP4 to an Image Sequence make it go any faster and is it more optimized?

Edit: I have converted the movie textures into image sequences and still when I press the Render Animation button the individual texters start rendering instead of the animation itself. Rendering just the current frame renders the scene normally.

Answer (score 0):

**HOW TO RENDER AN ANIMATION IN BLENDER**

STEP 1: **go to your output properties in the properties tab.**
[image]

STEP 2:**select your output(where you want the animation to be saved eg. a specific folder and in which name it should be saved**

STEP3:
**change your file format into FFmpeg[(recommended)(if you are rendering a n animation)]from PNG**
[image]

step 4: ****CHANGE THE ENCODING CONTAINER TO MPEG 4 FROM INSTEAD OF MATROSKA****
[image]

step 5: (OPTIONAL): **if you have audio in your animation, simply go to audio>Audio Codec and select MP3 instead of no audio.**
[image]

STEP 6: **then go up to your render options then select render animation or F12 on your keypad.**
[image]

HOPE THIS HELPED!!!

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but that's not what I'm looking for. I know how to render animations. My issue is that every time I start the render, one of the movie clip textures starts being rendered and exported as an image sequence instead of the animation itself. Right now I'm trying to manually export the individual movie textures and use them as image sequence textures and see if that helps.

Comment: @kiRadon ok i guess i didn't read the question properly :) sorry